# ion-slide-box not working in windows-phone 8.1

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, windows-phone-8.1

**HTML**

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="true" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">

  <ion-slide style="padding-top:62px;overflow-y:auto;background-color:#fff3ca" >
     <img src="images/masterek banr.png" style="width:100%; margin-top:-10px;border-radius: 15px;border: 3px solid;border-color: #FAFAFA;" />
    <div class="page-views pviews">
    <p>
    Some Test
     </p>
     </div>
     </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide style="padding-top:62px;overflow-y:auto;background-color:#fff3ca" >
     <img src="images/masterek banr.png" style="width:100%; margin-top:-10px;border-radius: 15px;border: 3px solid;border-color: #FAFAFA;" />
    <div class="page-views pviews">
    <p>
    Some Test
     </p>
     </div>
     </ion-slide>
 <ion-slide style="padding-top:62px;overflow-y:auto;background-color:#fff3ca" >
     <img src="images/masterek banr.png" style="width:100%; margin-top:-10px;border-radius: 15px;border: 3px solid;border-color: #FAFAFA;" />
    <div class="page-views pviews">
    <p>
    Some Test
     </p>
     </div>
     </ion-slide>
 <ion-slide style="padding-top:62px;overflow-y:auto;background-color:#fff3ca" >
     <img src="images/masterek banr.png" style="width:100%; margin-top:-10px;border-radius: 15px;border: 3px solid;border-color: #FAFAFA;" />
    <div class="page-views pviews">
    <p>
    Some Test
     </p>
     </div>
     </ion-slide>
     </ion-slide-box>
```

This slide box works perfectly fine in Android and iOS but not on windows phone using ionic 1.2.4

Comment: which version of Ionic 1, 1.x?....

Comment: Im not sure how well Ionic supports Windows Phone 8 (see Windows 10 section)... http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-1-2/ so maybe this is one of the issues. What i'd like to suggest is try using the `ion-slides` directive which uses swiper.js because the `ion-slide-box` will become deprecated anyway in future versions of 1.x

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionSlides/